# -bash: vdo: command not found in centos stream 9

Tags: linux, centos, storage

After installing vdo and kmod-kvdo via dnf, the vdo command doesn't work. Systemctl doesn't recognize vdo.service as well.

Vdo version: 8.1.0.316

Vdo release: 1.el9.1

I looked everywhere for a solution and didn't find any.

I'm new to linux so I don't have much knowledge...

Thank you all in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old Python VDO user space tools [are no longer available in CentOS/RHEL 9](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9-beta/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_9/assembly_file-systems-and-storage_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-9#ref_storage-file-systems-and-storage_assembly_file-systems-and-storage) (it was [deprecated in 8.5](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/8.5_release_notes/deprecated_functionality)). VDO technology is now integrated into LVM, you can create deduplicated and/or compressed LVs, see [lvmvdo man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmvdo.7.html) or [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9-beta/html/deduplicating_and_compressing_logical_volumes_on_rhel/introduction-to-vdo-on-lvm_deduplicating-and-compressing-logical-volumes-on-rhel) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I just finished installing VDO on RHEL9 and was working performing the create VDO command and got the same command not found error. I thought I was losing it.